# Parsing JSON result in android

Tags: java, android, json

Hi i have the following JSON result:

```
{
    "returnCode": "1",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "109",
            "account_id": "159",
            "created_on": "2013-11-29 10:46:41",
            "title": "iphone 5",
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "price": "500",
            "is_owner": "0",
            "photoCount": 1,
            "commentList": [
                {
                    "account_id": "159",
                    "created_on": "2013-11-29 10:46:41",
                    "name": "Jane Doe",
                    "comment": "Blah.. blah... blah..."
                },
                {
                    "id": "134",
                    "account_id": "144",
                    "created_on": "2013-12-04 16:21:49",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "comment": "Blah.. blah.. blah..."
                }
            ],
            "count_like": "1",
            "count_dislike": "0",
            "count_favorite": "0",
            "count_comment": "1",
            "is_order": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Comment> getComments(String jData) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
    ArrayList<Comment> cList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    JSONArray jCommentArr = jObj.getJSONArray("commentList");

    servResponse = (int) jObj.getInt("returnCode");
    if(servResponse == 1){
        for(int i=0; i<jCommentArr.length(); i++)
        {
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            JSONObject jComment = jCommentArr.getJSONObject(i);

            comment.commenterId = (int) jComment.getInt("account_id");
            comment.commenterName = (String) jComment.getString("name");
            comment.commentMessage = (String) jComment.getString("comment");
            comment.postDate = (String) jComment.getString("created_on");

            cList.add(comment);
        }
    }
    return cList;
}
```

I am only interested with the array of comments in the JSON (Specified with the "commentList" tag.

However, my code always throws a JSON exception saying that the cList contains null value.
Can anyone points out what when wrong with my code?

Thx

Comment: keep scrolling down, it is below the JSON result. Let me edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
ArrayList<Comment> cList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
servResponse = Integer.parseInt(jObj.getString("returnCode").trim());
JSONArray objarr = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
for(int i = 0;i< objarr.length();i++){
    JSONObject jCment = objarr.getJSONObject(i);
    if(servResponse == 1){
       JSONArray jCommentArr = jCment.getJSONArray("commentList");
          for(int j=0; j<jCommentArr.length(); j++)
          {
              Comment comment = new Comment();
              JSONObject jComment = jCommentArr.getJSONObject(j);

              comment.commenterId = Integer.parseInt(jComment.getString("account_id").trim());
              comment.commenterName = jComment.getString("name").trim();
              comment.commentMessage = jComment.getString("comment").trim();
              comment.postDate = jComment.getString("created_on").trim();

              cList.add(comment);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: objarr.getJSONArray() expects int index as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

-> `JSONArray jCommentArr = jObj.getJSONArray("commentList");`

change to-> `JSONArray jCommentArr = jObj.getJSONArray("result");`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
 ArrayList<Comment> cList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
 JSONArray jTemp = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
 JSONArray jCommentArr = jTemp.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("commentList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you directly access the commentList which is a value contained inside the result array. You have to access it first.

```
JSONArray commentList = jObj.getJSONArray("result").getJSONArray("commentList");
```